# Carousel Failure Unexplained

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this carousel but does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why. I have this function inside `$(document).ready()` but when I click `next`/`prev`, it does not work. So I think maybe I'm doing something wrong as it does not seem to be picking it up at all.

HTML:

```
<div id="jb-video-carousel">
  <span class="business-left"></span>
  <ul class="jb-videos-container">
    <li class="jb-video-container">test</li>
    <li class="jb-video-container">test</li>
    <li class="jb-video-container">test</li>
    <li class="jb-video-container">test</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="business-right"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    var defaults = {
        container: '.jb-videos-container',
        wrap: '.jb-video-carousel',
        item: '.jb-video-container',
        btnPrev: '.business-left',
        btnNext: '.business-right'
    };

    var itemsPerPage = 0,
        totalPages = 0,
        page = 1,
        $items = $(defaults.item, el),
        $wrapper = $(defaults.wrap, el),
        $container = $(defaults.container, el),
        $next = $(defaults.btnNext, el),
        $prev = $(defaults.btnPrev, el),
        itemWidth = $items.eq(0).outerWidth(true),
        margin = itemWidth - $items.eq(0).width(),

    moveToPage = function (n) {
        var scalar = n > 1 ? n - 1 : 0,
            rem = $items.length - (scalar * itemsPerPage),
            left = 0;

        if (rem < itemsPerPage) {
            left = (($items.length) * itemWidth) - $wrapper.width();
        } else {
            left = scalar * (itemsPerPage * itemWidth);
        }

        $container.css('left', -left);
        page = n;
    },

    layout = function () {
        itemsPerPage = Math.floor(($wrapper.outerWidth() + margin) / itemWidth);
        totalPages = Math.ceil($items.length / itemsPerPage);

        if (totalPages === 1) {
            $prev.hide();
            $next.hide();
        }
        else {
            $prev.show();
            $next.show();
        }
    },

    onResize = function () {
        layout();
        moveToPage(page);
    },

    pagePrev = function () {
        var destination = page - 1;
        if (destination <= 0) {
            destination = 1;
        }
        moveToPage(destination);
    },

    pageNext = function () {
        var destination = page + 1;
        if (destination > totalPages) {
            destination = totalPages;
        }
        moveToPage(destination);
    };

    $container.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'width': (itemWidth * $items.length)
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function (evt) {
        onResize(evt);
    });

    $next.on('click', function (evt) {
        pageNext();
        return false;
    });

    $prev.on('click', function (evt) {
        pagePrev();
        return false;
    });

    domready(function () {
        setTimeout(onResize);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: Of course, no errors at all

Comment: Please create a [MCVE example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a codepen or jsfiddle link for us to test/ check it out. This makes the testing process easier and gives you a chance to test this code stand alone.

Comment: No worries will do this now for you

Comment: You forgot to execute the function, the last line should be `}());`. Then you have `el is not defined` errors in `$items = $(defaults.item, el)` and following lines, finally `domready` is undefined, just use `$(function(){...})`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L4v036gf/

Comment: additionally to pawels answer, the last domready should rather be a resize hook to the window object ...

Comment: Note: http://jsfiddle.net/L4v036gf/1/ --> set as base to be reached at the url without the version number.

Tip: `var localOptions = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`

and: you are still not calling your function that now includes el and options.

Comment: How to i call those? sorry im a little new to JS still

Answer (score 3):

Your anonymous function is not being executed at all:

```
(function() {});   // declares an anonymous function (useless)
(function() {})(); // declares AND EXECUTES an anonymous function instantly
```

So, you have to add a pair of parentheses before the last semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between declaring a function and in the execution of a function. Why you are doing it in your code is declaring an anonymous function. In order to call that function, you should put a pair of parenthesis `()` at its end followed by a semi-colon `;` like:

```
(function() {
    // function definition
}());
```

Comment: better to use the anonymous-declaration-execution paradigm way, as lxg shows us below.